# How do I know exact extension of a Word document in Java

Tags: java, file-io, ms-word, java-io

I have a program which copies a word file (docx/doc) as follows: 
A source file which is doc/docx is first copied to a temporary raw file where the extension is lost. Now the contents of this temporary raw file are to be copied to a file with suitable extension(doc/docx). Since, nothing is known at this point about the original file, it is required here to derive extension of the source Word Document from its contents.

```
   InputStream in = new FileInputStream ( src );
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream ( dst );
    byte [] buf = new byte [1024];
    int len;
    while ( ( len = in.read ( buf ) ) > 0 ) {
        out.write ( buf, 0, len );
    }
```

Destination `dst` is a raw file without any extension (say, 'sample-file'), which I can't change. The source`src` may be a 'doc' or a 'docx' type.
Now, as an output, I need to copy the contents of `dst` to a Word Document with proper format as of `src`(this 'proper format' is important here, otherwise the document is rendered useless). Since `dst` doesn't have any extension, I cannot find the file format by just looking at the name. Is there a way, I can retrieve the file extension from file contents? Hopefully, Word document must have some meta-data containing this information.

Comment: If I am correct you want to know the input file(src) extension ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension : File extensions  are commonly used to imply information about the way data might be stored in the file.  There is no guarantee.. You need to open the file and look for its type

Comment: Does https://code.google.com/p/filetype-identifier/  help? You can see the code and adopt for your use.

Comment: @Jayan That's the intension. I am looking for determining file type based on contents.

Comment: how is this off-topic? Help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Word_Document_%28DOC%29
This link details lots of different file types. It describes the headers of both DOC and DOCX files, so you should be able to parse the files and determine what kind they are.

Looking at the link, .doc files are OLE Compound Files, the file should have the following binary header:

```
d0 cf 11 e0 a1 b1 1a e1
```

In constrast, .docx files will have the binary signature:

```
50 4b
```

Also, DOCX files are in ZIP format, in which the first two bytes are the letters PK (after ZIP's creator, Phil Katz).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I never thought about such question but is's may be very useful for me in futuer

Comment: @abksrv: If you think the answer helped, please "accept it" as answer. It is a good practice, and it would be easier for other users/readers as well :-)

Comment: Sorry. I havn't no accept button.

Comment: The accept button is only for those who asked the question. Others are only free to upvote/downvote answers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the `DOCX` files contents in binary format the first two characters will be **"PK"**. You can use the same to identify if its a `DOCX` file or not.